# Open Telemetry .NET Memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, open-telemetry

When I use open-telemetry libraries in my .NET web api, the Memory consumption start growing until it reach pod memory limit and the pod is restarted.
Memory of pod increased from 375MB to 506MB in 6hrs (+35%). It increased to 710MB in next 10hrs then the pod was restarted.
The web api (dev environment) has very low and constant traffic around 4req/s (90% is from FronDoor health checks)

I did two gcdumps (with 6hrs distance), compared them and I could see that the second gcdump had:
106.078 more Activity objects.
1.060.780 more DiagNode<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>
etc.

I have compared gcdumps in visual studio and there are top 15 objects with the highest Inclusive Size Diff.:
[image]

There are libraries versions:

```
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.5.1-beta.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.5.1-beta.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Runtime" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient" Version="1.5.1-beta.1" />
```

Method with configuration used in Stratup.cs:

```
       public static IServiceCollection SetupOpenTelemetry(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, TracingOptions options)
        {
            if (!options.OpenTelemetry.Enabled)
                return services;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.OpenTelemetry.EndpointUrl))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("OpenTelemetry EndpointUrl is not configured.");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.OpenTelemetry.ServiceName))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("OpenTelemetry ServiceName is not configured.");

            var environmentOptions = configuration.GetRequiredSection(EnvironmentOptions.SectionName).Get<EnvironmentOptions>()
                ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot bind {EnvironmentOptions.SectionName} section.");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environmentOptions.Name))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Environment Name is not configured.");

            var serviceAttributes = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("service.version", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("service.environment", environmentOptions.Name)
            };

            var resourceBuilder =
                ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                    .AddService(options.OpenTelemetry.ServiceName)
                    .AddAttributes(serviceAttributes);

            services.AddOpenTelemetry()
                .WithMetrics(builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .SetResourceBuilder(resourceBuilder) 
                        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                        .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                        .AddOtlpExporter(exporter =>
                        {
                            exporter.Endpoint = new Uri(options.OpenTelemetry.EndpointUrl);
                            exporter.Headers = $"lightstep-access-token={options.OpenTelemetry.AccessToken}";
                        });
                })
                .WithTracing(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddSource("Npgsql")
                    .SetResourceBuilder(resourceBuilder)
                    .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(o =>
                    {
                        o.RecordException = true;
                        o.EnrichWithHttpRequest = (activity, request) =>
                        {
                            activity.SetTag("size", request.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength ?? 0);
                        };
                        o.EnrichWithException = (activity, exception) =>
                        {
                            activity.SetTag("stackTrace", exception.StackTrace);
                        };
                    })
                    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation(o =>
                    {
                        o.RecordException = true;
                        o.EnrichWithException = (activity, exception) =>
                        {
                            activity.SetTag("stackTrace", exception.StackTrace);
                        };
                    })
                    .AddSqlClientInstrumentation(o =>
                    {
                        o.RecordException = true;
                        o.SetDbStatementForText = true;
                        o.EnableConnectionLevelAttributes = true;
                    })
                    .AddOtlpExporter(o =>
                    {
                        o.Endpoint = new Uri(options.OpenTelemetry.EndpointUrl);
                        o.Headers = $"lightstep-access-token={options.OpenTelemetry.AccessToken}";
                    });

                    if (options.OpenTelemetry.EnableConsoleExport)
                    {
                        builder.AddConsoleExporter();
                    }
                });

            return services;
        }
```

The EndpointUrl for OtlpExporter is: **https://ingest.lightstep.com**

Does anyone idea what could be wrong and why Activity objects and others are not released from Memory?
Have you similar experience?

Comment: I don't have an actual answer, just a methodology to track it down (It's not an experience I've had running the instrumentation at significant scale). Try removing the SqlClient instrumentation and the enrichers (You're using Npgsql which should cover you over SqlClient). Feel free to drop on the CNCF slack to have a proper discussion though. You could also try sending to the collector too, to rule out Lightstep's ingest being the issue.

Comment: You're right, removing .AddSource("Npgsql") helped and the memory consumption is now stable and doesn't grow.